# Bezier curvature extrema

Tags: geometry, polynomials, bezier-curve, spline

For a planar cubic Bezier curve $B (x(t),y(t))$, I would like to find the values of parameter $t$ where the curvature (or curvature radius) is greatest/smallest. The formula for curvature is:

$$r = \dfrac{(x'^2+y'^2)^{(3/2)}}{x' (t) y''(t) - y'(t) x''(t)}$$

The problem is that there is that square root in it so I was wondering whether it is not possible to express the curvature extrema by some combination of the curve derivatives?

The idea is that for finding, say, the values where the slope of the curve is parallel to x-axis one needs to solve the quadratic function of the curve's first derivative. So I thought that maybe the extremes are in fact the values where the acceleration along the curve (or something similar) is greatest/smallest and I hoped that it would be possible to write it down as a polynomial.

Comment: idea: The curvature is maximized at the same points that the squared curvature is maximized.

Comment: You should place norm in the denominator as well.

Comment: Note that the radius of curvature can become infinite at an inflexion point.

Comment: @JeanMarie: If $\times$ represents the two-dimensional analog of cross product ($(x_a,y_a)\times(x_b,y_b) = x_a y_b - x_b y_a$), then there is no need for the norm in the denominator. Indeed, I claim it is harmful, because the sign of the product indicates whether the second vector is counterclockwise or clockwise from the first. Of course, we don't know yet if this is a 2D or 3D problem...

Comment: @NominalAnimal It's 2D, please see the edit.

Comment: @Nominal Animal You are right.

Comment: @Faaf I am sorry for the inadequate transformation. Maybe it would be better to write this radius of curvature under the nonambiguous form $\dfrac{(x'^2+y'^2)^{(3/2)}}{x' (t) y''(t) - y'(t) x''(t)}$. I let you do the transformation you want.

Comment: A partial answer to your questionning: the extrema (maxima or minima) of the acceleration $\gamma(t)$ are situated either in $B(0)$ or in $B(1)$ because it is a degree one expression : see formula $\mathbf {B} ''(t)=6(1-t)(\mathbf {P} _{2}-2\mathbf {P} _{1}+\mathbf {P} _{0})+6t(\mathbf {P} _{3}-2\mathbf {P} _{2}+\mathbf {P} _{1})$ (otherwise said $\gamma(t)=6(1-t) \gamma(0)+6 t \gamma(1)$) that can be found in the very interesting article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Short summary

The points of extremal curvature which are not inflection points will correspond to roots of the quintic polynomial

$$(x'''y' - x'y''')(x'^2 + y'^2)-3(x'x'' + y'y'')(x''y' - x'y'')$$

Finding these roots generally requires numeric methods; there can be no simple formula using radicals (i.e. fractional exponents) nor a ruler and compass construction of the points in question.

### Avoiding square roots

> The problem is that there is that square root in it

For this I'd indeed go with John's comment: the extrema of the curvature are extrema of the squared curvature. The converse may not hold if the curvature passes through zero, but if you are interested in the extrema of the absolute value of the curvature, then all maxima of the squared curvature will be relevant. So look at

$$k^2=\frac{(x'\,y'' - y'\,x'')^2}{(x'^2+y'^2)^3}$$

### Characterizing extrema

Compute the derivative of that with respect to $t$, concentrate on the numerator of the resulting rational function, and you will get [a polynomial of degree $7$ in $t$](https://gist.github.com/gagern/4261bf649666f7840506e0636029bf6f). It contains two factors: one of degree $2$ which is equivalent to $x'\,y'' - y'\,x''$ and describes the inflection points where the curvature is zero. And one of degree $5$ which gives you the remaining points of extremal curvature.

### A concrete and illustrated example

I tried to determine whether all of these points are indeed relevant, and found several situations where all seven critical values for $t$ were real numbers between $0$ and $1$. So far I haven't found a really beautiful setup, where all seven points are easy to see, with sufficient distance between them and sufficient differences in curvature. Here is the best I have so far:

$$P_1=(0,4),P_2=(5,4),P_3=(7,0),P_4=(5,3)\\
t\in\{0.211, 0.326, 0.508, 0.634, 0.734, 0.852, 0.920\}$$

The curves looks like depicted below. Control points in cyan, inflection points in magenta and other extremal curvature points in red. I also included the osculating circles (light red) resp. tangent lines (light magenta) at the critical points, but they are all so close together that it's really hard to see.

[image: Graph of example curve with 7 curvature extrema]

Below is what the curvature looks like for the example above. It clearly depicts the fact that the curvature hardly differs at all between some of these extremal points, while at one maximum it's so large that it's way off the graph. I'm sorry I don't have a more balanced example.

[image: Plot of curvature for the above example]

### Simple closed form impossible

Since there are at least five (and depending on your definition perhaps even seven) relevant solutions, [I doubt you can get around solving this numerically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Finding_roots_of_a_quintic_equation). And if you do tackle this numerically, the above approach is probably easiest to understand and implement, so I'd not try looking for a different description. But more on that in the next section.

To be more precise: the five non-inflection points of extremal curvature in the example above are the roots of

$$18056\,t^5 - 48720\,t^4 + 49540\,t^3 - 23550\,t^2 + 5200\,t - 425 = 0$$

The [Galois group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_group) of this polynomial is [$S_5$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group), so there can be no way to describe its roots using radicals. Since most ruler and compass geometric constructions can't perform operations more complex than taking square roots, that also rules out reasonably simple geometric descriptions of these points.

### Numeric approach

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Cubic_B.C3.A9zier_curves) (and thanks to the comment by Jean Marie), the derivatives of your point can be computed like this:

\begin{align*}
B(t)&=(1-t)^3\,P_1+3(1-t)^2t\,P_2+3(1-t)t^2\,P_3+t^3\,P_4\\
B'(t)&=3(1-t)^2\,(P_2-P_1)+6(1-t)t\,(P_3-P_2)+3t^2\,(P_4-P_3)\\
B''(t)&=6(1-t)\,(P_3-2P_2+P_1)+6t\,(P_4-2P_3+P_2)\\
B'''(t)&=6(P_4-3P_3+3P_2-P_1)\\
B''''(t)&=0
\end{align*}

According to my computer algebra system, and unless I made a mistake, the derivative of the squared curvature is

$$\frac{\mathrm d\,k^2}{\mathrm dt}=
2\frac{\bigl(x''y' - x'y''\bigr)\bigl((x'''y' - x'y''')(x'^2 + y'^2)
-3(x'x'' + y'y'')(x''y' - x'y'')\bigr)}{(x'^2 + y'^2)^4}$$

Since you want this to be zero, you can ignore the denominator here. If you don't care about the inflection points, you can omit the first parenthesis in the numerator as well. If you know the coordinates of your four points, you can compute the coefficients of $t$ in the individual polynomials, combine them to the resulting polynomial (of degree 5 if you dropped the inflection condition or 7 if not) and then [find roots of that polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm#Finding_roots_of_polynomials) numerically.

It is interesting to note that $(x'''y' - x'y''')$ has degree $1$ in $t$ and $(x''y' - x'y'')$ has degree $2$ in $t$, even though the degrees of the involved terms would suggest a higher resulting degree. But the terms in the highest coefficient cancel out, otherwise the second big parenthesis in the numerator would be a polynomial of degree $6$. If you do this in integer arithmetic, you will be able to cancel a common factor of $162$ from all the coefficients of this polynomial, but for floating point arithmetic it doesn't really matter.

### Responses to comments

I'll try to answer some questions from your comment.

> why at most 7 roots?

Because the relevant condition can be expressed as a polynomial of degree $7$ so there can never be more than these.

> If I image a cubic Bezier I have a hard time finding seven places where the curvature could be most extreme.

I also have a hard time finding one where all the different points and curvatures can be seen well. But the example above should illustrate the kind of situation this is about. Whether you consider five or seven solutions depends on whether you care about inflection points with zero curvature or not.

> Also, perhaps there are other ways to get the positions than squaring the curvature formula?

There may well be. But the solutions have to be equivalent. At least in the example above, we know that there are five resp. seven relevant points, so other solution cannot end up with a simpler description of these solutions. At least not simpler in terms of the degree of the describing polynomial.

> And lastly, would something like the dot product of first and second derivative work? If not, why? That would result polynomial of degree 3.

Well, that's simply due to the definition of the curvature. While it sounds plausible that this dot product of yours would share some properties of curvature, it's a different quantity with different extremal parameters, so it does not fit the established concept of curvature as the inverse radius of osculating circles.

If you can't use that dot product all by itself, you could instead use it as part of a larger formula. Towards that goeal, the determinant (or 2d cross product, or whatever you want to call it) is proportional to the sine of the angle, just as the dot product is proportional to the cosine. So generally speaking you have

$$\langle v,w\rangle^2+(v\times w)^2=\lVert v\rVert^2\cdot\lVert w\rVert^2$$

for arbitrary vectors $v$ and $w$. Which means that in the case at hand you could write the squared curvature as

$$k^2=\frac{(x'^2+y'^2)(x''^2+y''^2)-(x'x''+y'y'')^2}{(x'^2+y'^2)^3}$$

but you gain nothing by doing this. The actual increase in degree comes from computing the derivative of such an expression, in order to find the extrema.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But unfortunately, this creates even more questions for me. Please, don't get me wrong, I'm really not very good at this but I have to wonder: why at most 7 roots? If I image a cubic Bezier I have a hard time finding seven places where the curvature could be most extreme. Also, perhaps there are other ways to get the positions than squaring the curvature formula? And lastly, would something like the dot product of first and second derivative work? If not, why? That would result polynomial of degree 3.

Comment: I found my mistake. Had had one exponent 3 which should have been 3 in one of my formulas. Will try to reproduce with correct code.

Comment: @Faaf: I've corrected my example, and I've included some replies to your comment as part of my post. Hope this helps. I'm still looking for a nicer example.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it does help! Please, a last question about your comment on the dot product of first and second derivative. In your last reply, why did you square it? I meant taking the derivatives of the cubic Bezier and compute the dot product of those, that would(?) be polynomial of third degree. In general, if I'm interested in curvature extrema, why is it not sufficient to find where the "velocity" along the curve is the greatest? I mean, what I try to say, if I square the curvature formula I get 7th degree polynomial, ok. But why not simply take the dot product, which would be degree 3?

Comment: @Faaf: To put it simply: because curvature is not defined this way. You might end with something which *might* resemble some aspects of curvature on an intuitive level, but you would not get *the* mathematically defined and agreed-upon concept of curvature as the inverse radius of the osculating circle. To get that, you have to use the dot product as part of the formula, and that's where squaring it seemed the most reasonable operation to me.

Comment: Ad "It contains two factors:...": if I was not interested in the inflection points, would it be possible to somehow obtain just the degree 5 polynomial? I mean the gist you linked to, is it possible to split it into those two factors?

Comment: @Faaf: Sure. I posted that gist before I noticed that this polynomial factors. I just updated the gist to include the factorization as well. But the polynomials are still huge, so when doing this numerically you'll want to investigate ways for not computing them from this expanded form, but instead deriving them from the given formula and treating all the variables as constant except for $t$.

Comment: Thank you! One last question: how do I know that this degree 2 polynomial signifies only the inflection points? I mean, can it happen that one inflection point is "hidden" in first polynomial and the second inflection point in the other one?

Comment: @Faaf: The degree two factor is equal to $x'y''-y'x''$, so if that is zero, then the numerator of my fraction is zero, so the curvature is zero, so it's an inflection point. If you do numerical computations, you can use this fact: perhaps you can compute the coefficients of the degree 7 polynomial numerically. If you do, also compute those of the degree 2 polynomial, and since you know that one is a factor of the other, you can perform polynomial devision and simply trust there will be no remainder, even if numerical error may suggest otherwise.

Comment: Got it, thanks again!

Comment: @Faaf: I updated my answer to include some aspects covered in our comments, and also to provide a formula which may be more feasible than the fully expanded beast I pasted on gist.